# How to Optimally Add, Multiply and Average Very Large Data Sets in MATLAB Using parfor

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, bigdata, parfor

I would like to introduce an interesting MATLAB programming problem I’ve encountered in my research.  The solution may be of use to people doing computations on very large data sets.  It involves striking a balance between RAM and CPU usage using parfor.  Because my data is so large, files must be read in over and over again to be processed.  The other issue it introduces is finding an optimal algorithm for multiplication, summation and averaging of very large vectors and matrices.

I have found a solution, but it’s time intensive and I would like too see if the community sees any room for improvement.  Here’s the general form of the problem.

Suppose we have about 30,000 functions that we’ve taken the Fourier transforms of.  Each transform has the form e(k)=a(k)+b(k)*i where k is the magnitude of a wavevector, a is the real component and b is the imaginary component.  Each of these transforms is saved to file as a 2-column table with the structure below.  The number of elements in each vector is about N=1e6.  This means that each of these files is 1/64 GB in size.  Note that the values of k_i are not necessarily in order.

**k | Re(e)  Im(e)**

k_1 |  a(1)   b(1)

k_2  |  a(2)   b(2)

...  |

k_N  |  a(N)   b(N)

The goal is to cross-multiply each pair of modes and average the results over a set of about 50 fixed k-bands.  So for example, if we let the elements of vectors 5 and 7 be represented respectively as e5=a5+b5*i and e7=a7+b7*i we need

a5(1)*a7(1) + b5(1)*b7(1)

a5(2)*a7(2) + b5(2)*b7(2)

...

a5(N)*a7(N) + b5(N)*b7(N)

Each element of the above N-dimensional vector belongs within a single k-bin.  All the elements in each bin must be averaged and returned.  So at the end of one mode-mode comparison we end up with just 50 numbers.

I have at my disposal a computer with 512GB of RAM and 48 processors.  My version of MATLAB 2013a limits me to only opening 12 processors with parfor simultaneously on each instance of MATLAB that I run.  So what I’ve been doing is opening 4 versions of MATLAB, allocating 10 processors each, and sending the maximum amount of data to each processor without spilling over my self-imposed limit of 450 GB.

Naturally this involves my breaking the problem into blocks.  If I have 30000 vectors e, then I will have 30000^2 sets of these 50 cross-coefficients.  (It’s actually about half this since the problem is symmetric).  I decide to break my problem into blocks of size m=300.  This means I’d have 100 rows and columns of these blocks.  The code I’m running looks like this (I’m simplifying a bit to just include the relevant bits):

```matlab
for ii=1:100  % for each of the block-rows
    [a,b] = f_ReadModes(ii);  % this function reads modes 1 through 300 if ii=1, 
                              % modes 301 through 600 if ii=2 and so on
                              % “a” and “b” are matrices of size Nx300
                              % “a” contains the real vectors stored in columns, 
                              % “b” contains the imaginary vectors stored in columns

    for jj=ii:100  % for each of the block-columns in the upper triangle
        [c,d] = f_ReadModes(jj);  % same as above except this reads in a different 
                                  % set of 300 modes

        block = zeros(300,300,50);  % allocates space for the results. The first 
                                    % dimension corresponds to the "ii modes".
                                    % The 2nd dimension corresponds to the “jj”  
                                    % modes.  The 3rd dimension is for each k-bin.

        parfor rr=1:300  
            A = zeros(1,300,50);  % temporary storage to keep parfor happy
            ModeMult = bsxfun(@times,a(:,rr),c)+bsxfun(@times,b(:,rr),d);
                % My strategy is to cross multiply one mode by all the others before
                % moving on.  So when rr=6, I’m multiplying the 6th mode in a (and b)
                % by all the modes in c and d.  This would help fill in the 6th row
                % of block, i.e. block(6,:,:).

            for kk=1:50  % Now I average the results in each of the k-bins
                ind_dk = f_kbins(kk);  % this returns the rows of a,b,c,d and
                                       % ModeMult that lie within the the kk^th bin
                A(1,:,kk) = mean(ModeMult(ind_dk,:));  % average results in each bin
            end
            block(rr,:,:) = A;  % place the results in more permanent storage.
        end

        f_WriteBlock(block);  % writes the resulting cross-coefficient block to disk

    end
end
```

There are three bottlenecks in this problem:

1)  Read-in time

2)  Computing the products ac and bd then summing them (this is ModeMult)

3)  Averaging the results of step 2 in each k-bin

Bigger blocks are preferable since they necessitate fewer read-in’s.  However, the computations in steps 2 and 3 don’t automatically parallelize, so they have to be sent to individual processors using parfor.  Because the computational costs are high, utitlizing all the processors seems necessary.

The way my code is written, each processor needs enough memory to hold 4*N*m elements.  When m=300, this means each processor is using about 10 GB of RAM.  It would be nice if the memory requirement for each processor could be lowered somehow.  It would also be great if the computations in steps 2 and 3 could be rewritten to run more efficiently.  Any thoughts?

Comment: For the step (1), unless your data are on separate discs, you may not save that much time when trying to read in parallel from 4 different matlab sessions (there may even be cases where they will all interfere with each other and slow down the whole process). I would recommend you to test reading a significant number of block sequentially, then the same number of block with your 4 sessions. Time both operations and compare.